# NelmioApiDoc - Hide documentation section by default

Tags: symfony, swagger, nelmioapidocbundle

By default, ApiDoc lists out all operations for each API endpoint, like this:

[image: Expanded list]

In the [Swagger demo](http://petstore.swagger.io/#/), however, operations are hidden by default until the user chooses to show them.

[image: Hidden list]

Is there a configuration option for ApiDoc that will hide operations by default? I haven't found anything like this in the [documentation](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle/tree/master/Resources/doc).

Answer (score 1):

Documentation section can be hidden by default with parameter `default_sections_opened`:

```
nelmio_api_doc.default_sections_opened: false
```

Default value for this parameter is `true`. See [configuration reference](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/configuration-reference.rst).

Answer (score 0):

You must change your config.yml file like this (default_sections_opened to false):

```
nelmio_api_doc:
   name: 'API documentation'
   exclude_sections:     []
   **default_sections_opened:  false**
  motd:
    template:             'NelmioApiDocBundle::Components/motd.html.twig'
  request_listener:
    enabled:              true
    parameter:            _doc
  sandbox:
    enabled:              false
```